# How to abort early with Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

Tags: typescript

```
type PathFinder<
  TFieldValues,
  Key extends keyof TFieldValues = keyof TFieldValues,
> = Key extends string
  ? TFieldValues[Key] extends FileList
    ? Key
    : TFieldValues[Key] extends (ArrayChild)[] | Set<ArrayChild>
    ? `${Key}.${Indexes}`
    : TFieldValues[Key] extends object[]
    ? `${Key}.${Indexes}.${PathFinder<ArrayElementType<TFieldValues[Key]>>}`
    : TFieldValues[Key] extends Record<string, any>
    ? `${Key}.${PathFinder<TFieldValues[Key]>}`
    : Key
  : never;

type Works = PathFinder<{ test: string }> 
type Error = PathFinder<Record<string, any>> // cause error
```

I have the above type to type object path, however, some of my function's generic is `Recrod<string, any>` is there any way to skip or abort early so this error can be avoided?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJwQQzAUQDZQLZQHYgAqkUAPHAHwwC88MUAHiPgCYDOMCUyLA9nhjAwAFAEs8AMygIYhAJQBtALowA-LJgAuGHigA3aQG5goEjACSeFoygdqwGDAA%20MAAwPnMAIweXAJl8YAGZAgBZAgFZAgDZAgHZAgA5AgE5Ar3dHFy8fLO8AvK8QwvDCqMLYwoTC5MK0vL9Mzz9c5oLm4ubS5vLmyubq5trm%20s8g12NTaHgkVABhAAtRDBYaGDYQBHEAc08AI15eLGQ8TzwAV2w96U82MCuj-dFt8RBJ8GmABWQQBYAxcTWBCkDyEAFQFYANWQGHOtgANB4ANJQISMZhWDgAa1RvAksnBUJhcLsMBxYDxBNEEJY0NhCOAVFoKLRTFYHA2Wzw2w86jB1KJ9LYChZKnR7JgAKwABlRBsPI51CyFVoqTS6SSRaixWzMSJECgwItlixFCoXABlKAgcizI1LFYUFXqAAGABIAN4sgC%20ADpPZZrAxbN6XSrtPz1cTbFqwDqMewYLw9gArKAAYxAymdMHdXtRfoDVhsbELHu%20vwBxeBBtQmBw%20CIJFIkcFmtFFAoofDarbMdF9F1iYAShneAgWKROTt4TATmAnY5FbnPT7-eWfv9AdIW4TadHhR3u0vVcrHNpdAYEJNHB9YMwNmsK1vq6RR%20nx5Pp9zZ-POyZgCAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a recursive type that occasionally explodes because there's no base case for the recursion.  Rather than tackle the complex template literal stuff immediately, it always helps to reduce things to a more minimal example that exhibits the behavior in question.  For example:

```
type IffyRecursion<T> = T extends { x: infer U } ? [U, ...IffyRecursion<U>] : [];
```

`IffyRecursion<T>` produces a tuple type; if `T` has no `x` property (the base case), it evaluates to `[]`.  Otherwise, it evaluates to a tuple that starts with `T`'s `x` property, and ends with the `IffyRecursion` evaluated on that `x` property (the recursive step).  It works like this:

```
type One = { x: 1 };
type Okay = IffyRecursion<One> // [1]
```

Here there's one recursive step until the base case is reached.  We can add another step and it still works:

```
type Two = { x: One };
type StillOkay = IffyRecursion<Two>; // [One, 1]
```

But if you define a recursive tree-like data structure, you hit a problem:

```
type Tree = { x: Tree };
type Oops = IffyRecursion<Tree>; // error!!!
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
```

Oops, there's no base case.  Logically `Oops` should evaluate to the infinite tuple `[Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree, ...]`, which the compiler balks at.

---

So how can you fix it?  If you're sure the recursive type you're measuring is essentially correct and you just want to bail out after some depth of recursion, you can add a new type parameter corresponding to that depth.  Each time you recurse, you decrease the allowable depth, until such time as you reach zero depth, and then you bail out.  For example, I'll use a type parameter `D` of type `number`:

```
type Pred = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
type OkayRecursion<T, D extends number = 4> =
  [D] extends [0] ? ["Bail Out Here"] :
  T extends { x: infer U } ? [U, ...OkayRecursion<U, Pred[D]>] : [];
```

Here the `Pred` tuple is set up such that `Pred[n]` is the one less than `n` for small `n`.  So `Pred[5]` is `4`, and `Pred[4]` is `3`, etc.  When `D` is `0`, we will return `["Bail Out Here"]` for want of something better.

This doesn't change the behavior for the non-recursive types `One` and `Two`:

```
type Okay = OkayRecursion<One> // [1]
type StillOkay = OkayRecursion<Two> // [One, 1]
```

But when we try `Tree` with the default max depth of `4`, there is no longer a compiler warning.  Instead, we get the bail-out behavior:

```
type OkayNow = OkayRecursion<Tree>; // no error 
// type OkayNow = [Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree, "Bail Out Here"]
```

---

So that's the general approach I sometimes take in cases like this.  For your `PathFinder` type, I won't pretend to have followed closely what it's supposed to be doing, but if I apply the depth-limiter above to it, this is what comes out:

```
type PathFinder<
  TFieldValues,
  Key extends keyof TFieldValues = keyof TFieldValues,
  D extends number = 4,
  > =
  [D] extends [0] ? "EXPLODE" :
  Key extends string
  ? TFieldValues[Key] extends FileList
  ? Key
  : TFieldValues[Key] extends (ArrayChild)[] | Set<ArrayChild>
  ? `${Key}.${Indexes}`
  : TFieldValues[Key] extends object[]
  ? `${Key}.${Indexes}.${PathFinder<ArrayElementType<TFieldValues[Key]>,
    keyof ArrayElementType<TFieldValues[Key]>, Pred[D]>}`
  : TFieldValues[Key] extends Record<string, any>
  ? `${Key}.${PathFinder<TFieldValues[Key], keyof TFieldValues[Key], Pred[D]>}`
  : Key
  : never;
```

Obviously you'd need to think about what you want to happen if the bail-out condition is reached; the string `"EXPLODE"` is not likely to be desirable.  Anyway, then your `test` type bails out eventually with this monstrosity:

```
type test = PathFinder<Record<string, any>, string>
/* type test = string | `${string}.0` | `${string}.1` | `${string}.4` |
 `${string}.2` | `${string}.3` | `${string}.5` | `${string}.6` | `${string}.7` |
 `${string}.8` | `${string}.9` | `${string}.10` | `${string}.11` | `${string}.12` |
 `${string}.13` | `${string}.14` | `${string}.15` | ... 142 more ... | 
 `${string}.${string}.${string}.${string}.EXPLODE` */
```

Which is better than a compiler warning, I guess.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8gO1gXhgbxgDwFwwIwwC+A3KJLACoDuA9jKhjvEkaeNDBQE5Qrpa5uvVsGAIAhgFsoAZwjiAxrAAKXGgCMANlEnpgMGO1gBJAGamwAJSgKArlxkBLGggA8FAHz1OMKJhBQCAAmMvxMjgimUFwwAKpEMAD8MADasQA0MAB0OWYW1nYOzm6xHgC6MLgpZaQGRvAA1uJg3nlWNvZOLq6IUF4A9P2peGX6huQwAMogjpqacE0tqG0FncXutB7EMIOpvZkjY-VwNBChy+bthV1uQn3bu9FqXACEb2O7FBMRMiDiCDNxDMXDBHKE-EoZE4AG5QTQtIK8CAwf5BGAQGhQxxaFoRUwRRwBLIACgATABWAAcAE4AJSiQiieqqKBo1ApJCwriZAAMB0ypMyAGZMgAWTLkzIANkyAHZRmIpLJ5EoYAAxRyYVl6OoTBbNVZFboUTIAEV8-kCIRgCFsknU0W8oq8yDGBhSpoqfgCwVCKR5FWSKQARAAhcSzeC2EAwAAS0SgwYq2DdPm9VtCjFweMd8UISVSGWyOX1VzW3SLLKCHrK5UqqRqol1HFL3lLhpuPSQAyGKUOzdg01m80WbcWHfW1BoPb2SAOowHjWaADkaFQxwaOkbbjx7jshgg6E8aDEPkNjotV+v2XdMrfOLu74+YGGI5oozH4zwk8BGUyJgAglwXDNAAoto0gAl80CuABLowABFo+taPDiEELjwjAxI5jEFC0tUBYUPWnLRKQZAcMYwR+LI9BjAAPjAPL0fgzGksxQrMaKzHksxUrMbKzGUsx1LMXgTEGAxeB4KJbESfgHFyXgXGKTxil8YpAmKUJikiXJpLiTADGktJemyYZMCkgp5mksp1mqdZ6nWZp1nadZunmUKPJkfUQEgWAADCAAWsxsjAvxcBEADm5nqDQNDaP85m2vajoMTIYD2vFMWOJFEQgGR-4cMoQKBRqVFcK4YwUBqcJBAAauImi2LI6RjAA0lALTpr6MANJ1NCmJwNWaPVjXNecvX9YN1WOLVDVNS1Yzmt11rJQ6MSoOKYwumMNZIRmqQBgWwagQAGsoAAycCmqBwaVO1nX7T14VRWMyQzXNY2yCkHVgF6lo9Rq2gXWCIBvTAv1jIIw2jQtMg-Z1-3IaExK+c0QUhfhFQMZMUAgLBwHo8FI0eODAAGAAkaC-YQWRU5RiJajIhBk1DQ2zSN83jQjf1PdaGgAFY2CA1Tk1TNN02gDPUczkvFSApURIiFVo2A4E6IEIDQVA7gw1z32-bWrUGAYfVgANCGE2rEGa9rusc7D3OGx4mRVjWHgs2zH2c198OG3zoQFCeQSuC9CCRZk-xgKTBjJJT1OdbTVPy4r5X259cM82UmRmxb3uOwbiOuzw1aeh7rMGLgkOVzaUBct5EwBL83gp2VyuuEHXAh2HEcogg0eZD3pP9AAVOMHBNzGqA9+Z8c97TPJk7PVPz1keBLwxc8gBF4e06KG-6FvO+RbTpIbzAR9RbTQrn5fu9ZOSt8r9vV9ZFKT9oKvsoHxfz-H7TlIP6r2pEAl+98xKgP-mvdey9P5gJPmvM+hlD5-1fngG+sDV5KUgWgx+5kchZHwKKUkMBJAnlgAQ5Bv84FQNQffOhCCGG0zOpda6oEl4j36KIIAA)